# How to insert image using wordpress and store it inside upload folder?

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, file-type, getimagedata

i tried file upload code but i am confuse where to place image name and that i have given inside input type file.

i comment out this code
// $file_name   =   pathinfo($tmp_name ,PATHINFO_FILENAME).time().".".pathinfo($tmp_name ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// $file = $_FILES['your_meta_field']['tmp_name']['image'];

i am fresher at wordpress plugin development and this is new for me.

i seen soo many solution like there is function named **wp_get_attachment_image** located at plugin handbook.

with this code my insertion of image and other data is working successfully but image when i update then it says no image available i want my previous image name when i edit any post.

also it is not worked at fronend due to the reason of not properly image is stored.

i could not find my uploaded image inside upload folder.

**here is my code :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Store Plugin 
 * Plugin URI: https://example.com/plugins/store-plugins/
 * Description: This is a description of my store plugin.
 * Version: 2.3.1
 * Author: Khushbu 
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */
function db_active() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db'; 
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    store_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    latitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    longitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ) $charset_collate;";  
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  $result = dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_active');

function db_deactive() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db'; 
  $sql = "DROP TABLE $table;";
  $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_deactive');

function add_your_fields_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box(
    'your_custom_meta_box',          // ID of the meta box
    'Location Information',          // Title of the meta box
    'your_custom_meta_box_content',  // Callback function to generate the content
    'store_post',                     // Custom post type (your_post)
    'normal',                        // Placement - 'normal', 'advanced', 'side'
    'high'                           // Priority - 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
  );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box');

function create_post_your_post() {
    register_post_type('store_post',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
      'name'         => __('Store Post'),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'excerpt',
      'thumbnail',
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array(
      'post_tag',
      'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'store_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'store_post');
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_your_post');

function your_custom_meta_box_content($post) {
  $store_id = $post->ID;
  //$image = get_post_meta($store_id,'image',true);
  $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
  $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
  $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
  $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

  if ($image_id) {
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
    if ($image_src) {
      $image_url = $image_src[0];
    }
  }
  ?>      
  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Image:</label></b>
  <?php
  if (!empty($image_url)) {
    echo '<br><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" style="max-width: 200px;" /><br>';
  }
  ?>
    <input type="file" name="your_meta_field[image]" id="your_meta_field[image]" onchange="previewImage(event)">
  <img id="image-preview" src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url); ?>" height="120" width="150"/>
  <?php
  if (!empty($image_url)) {
    echo '<br><small>chosen image: ' . esc_html($image_url) . '</small>';
  } ?> <br><br>


  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Address:</label></b>
  <textarea name="your_meta_field[address]" id="your_meta_field[address]" rows="3" cols="30" style="width:500px;"><?php echo esc_attr($address);?></textarea><br><br>

  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Latitude:</label></b>
  <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[latitude]" id="your_meta_field[latitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($latitude); ?>"><br><br>

  <b><label for="your_meta_field">Longitude:</label></b>
  <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[longitude]" id="your_meta_field[longitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($longitude); ?>"><br><br>

  <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'your_meta_box_nonce'); ?>
  <?php
}
function save_your_custom_meta_box_data($post_id) {
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return;
  }
  if ('store_post' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
    return;
  }
  
  $meta_fields = isset($_POST['your_meta_field']) ? $_POST['your_meta_field'] : array();
  if (isset($_FILES['your_meta_field']['name']['image']) && !empty($_FILES['your_meta_field']['name']['image'])) 
  {
     $path_array = wp_upload_dir();
    // $file_name   =   pathinfo($tmp_name ,PATHINFO_FILENAME).time().".".pathinfo($tmp_name ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
    // $file = $_FILES['your_meta_field']['tmp_name']['image'];
     $file_name = $_FILES['your_meta_field']['name']['image'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['your_meta_field']['type']['image'];

    if (strpos($file_type, 'image') !== false) 
    {
      $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
      $uploaded_image = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['your_meta_field']['tmp_name']['image'], $upload_overrides);

      if ($uploaded_image && !isset($uploaded_image['error'])) 
      {
        // Delete previous image, if any
        $old_image_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', true);
        if ($old_image_id) 
        {
          wp_delete_attachment($old_image_id, true);
        }
        // Save the uploaded image URL and ID in post meta
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'image', $uploaded_image['url']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', $uploaded_image['id']);
      } 
      else 
      {
        // Error handling if image upload fails
        $upload_error = $uploaded_image['error'] ?? 'Image upload failed.';
        wp_die($upload_error);
      }
    }
    else
    {
        // Error handling if the file is not an image
        wp_die('Please upload an image file.');
    }
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['address'] ) )
  {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['address'] ) );  
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) )
  {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'latitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) );  
  }
  if ( isset( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'longitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) );
  }

  if (isset($meta_fields['image']) && isset($meta_fields['address']) && isset($meta_fields['latitude']) && isset($meta_fields['longitude'])) {
    $store_name = get_the_title($post_id);
    $description = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $image = _sanitize_text_fields($meta_fields['image']);
    $address = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']);
    $latitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']);
    $longitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']);

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row(
      $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE store_id = %d", $post_id)
    );

    if ($existing_record) {
      // If a record exists, update the existing record
      $wpdb->update(
        $table,
        array(
          'store_name' => $store_name,
          'description' => $description,
          'image' => $image,
          'address' => $address,
          'latitude' => $latitude,
          'longitude' => $longitude,
        ),
        array('store_id' => $post_id),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
        array('%d')
      );
    } else {
      // If no record exists, insert a new record
      $wpdb->insert(
        $table,
        array(
          'store_id' => $post_id,
          'store_name' => $store_name,
          'description' => $description,
          'image' => $image,
          'address' => $address,
          'latitude' => $latitude,
          'longitude' => $longitude,
        ),
        array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
      );
    }
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_your_custom_meta_box_data');
// my changes completed
?>
<script>
function previewImage(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById('image-preview');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this solution:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Store Plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://example.com/plugins/store-plugins/
 * Description: This is a description of my store plugin.
 * Version: 2.3.1
 * Author: Khushbu
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

function db_active() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    store_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    latitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    longitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    $result = dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_active');

function db_deactive() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table;";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_deactive');

function add_your_fields_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'your_custom_meta_box',          // ID of the meta box
        'Location Information',          // Title of the meta box
        'your_custom_meta_box_content',  // Callback function to generate the content
        'store_post',                     // Custom post type (your_post)
        'normal',                        // Placement - 'normal', 'advanced', 'side'
        'high'                           // Priority - 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box');

function create_post_your_post() {
    register_post_type('store_post',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'         => __('Store Post'),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'thumbnail',
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array(
                'post_tag',
                'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'store_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'store_post');
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_your_post');

add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', function() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} );

function your_custom_meta_box_content($post) {
    $store_id = $post->ID;

    //$image = get_post_meta($store_id,'image',true);
    $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
    $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
    $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
    $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

    $default_url = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
    $image_url = '';
    if ($image_id) {
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
        if ($image_src) {
            $image_url = $image_src[0];
            $image_url = esc_url($image_url);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Image:</label></b>
    <?php
    if (!empty($image_url)) {
        echo '<br><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" style="max-width: 200px;" /><br>';
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        function previewImage(event) {
            var image = document.getElementById('image-preview');
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="your_meta_field[image]" onchange="previewImage(event)">
    <img id="image-preview" src="<?php echo !empty($image_url) ? $image_url : $default_url; ?>" height="120" width="150"/>
    <?php
    if (!empty($image_url)) {
        echo '<br><small>chosen image: ' . esc_html($image_url) . '</small>';
    } ?> <br><br>


    <b><label for="your_meta_field[image]">Address:</label></b>
    <textarea name="your_meta_field[address]" id="your_meta_field[address]" rows="3" cols="30" style="width:500px;"><?php echo esc_attr($address);?></textarea><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Latitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[latitude]" id="your_meta_field[latitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($latitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Longitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[longitude]" id="your_meta_field[longitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($longitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'your_meta_box_nonce'); ?>
    <?php
}
function save_your_custom_meta_box_data($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return;
    }
    if ('store_post' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    $meta_fields = isset($_POST['your_meta_field']) ? $_POST['your_meta_field'] : array();
    if (isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        if (strpos($file_type, 'image') !== false)
        {
            $uploaded_image = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['image'], ['test_form' => false]);

            if ($uploaded_image && empty($uploaded_image['error']))
            {
                // Delete previous image, if any
                $old_image_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', true);
                if ($old_image_id)
                {
                    wp_delete_attachment($old_image_id, true);
                }
                // Save the uploaded image URL and ID in post meta
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'image', $uploaded_image['url']);

                $attachment = array(
                    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $uploaded_image['file'] ),
                    'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_image['type'],
                    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploaded_image['file'] ) ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                );

                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploaded_image['file'], $post_id );
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_image['file'] );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', $attach_id);

            }
            else
            {
                // Error handling if image upload fails
                $upload_error = $uploaded_image['error'] ?? 'Image upload failed.';
                wp_die($upload_error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Error handling if the file is not an image
            wp_die('Please upload an image file.');
        }
    }
    if ( isset( $meta_fields['address'] ) )
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['address'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) )
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'latitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['latitude'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'longitude', sanitize_text_field( $meta_fields['longitude'] ) );
    }

    if (isset($meta_fields['image']) && isset($meta_fields['address']) && isset($meta_fields['latitude']) && isset($meta_fields['longitude'])) {
        $store_name = get_the_title($post_id);
        $description = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
        $image = _sanitize_text_fields($meta_fields['image']);
        $address = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']);
        $latitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']);
        $longitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']);

        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
        $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row(
            $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE store_id = %d", $post_id)
        );

        if ($existing_record) {
            // If a record exists, update the existing record
            $wpdb->update(
                $table,
                array(
                    'store_name' => $store_name,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'image' => $image,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'latitude' => $latitude,
                    'longitude' => $longitude,
                ),
                array('store_id' => $post_id),
                array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
                array('%d')
            );
        } else {
            // If no record exists, insert a new record
            $wpdb->insert(
                $table,
                array(
                    'store_id' => $post_id,
                    'store_name' => $store_name,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'image' => $image,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'latitude' => $latitude,
                    'longitude' => $longitude,
                ),
                array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_your_custom_meta_box_data');
```

Comment: i have tried your code thank you so much for your reply. your given code is fulfilled my requirement of saving image to upload folder and after update that uploaded image stays on page. 

-Thank You : )
@OlehKosarenko

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer that works well as database insertion, frontend that i have coded and backend working well.

here is my updated code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Store Plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://example.com/plugins/store-plugins/
 * Description: This is a description of my store plugin.
 * Version: 2.3.1
 * Author: Khushbu
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

function db_active() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    store_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    -- image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    latitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    longitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    $result = dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_active');

function db_deactive() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table;";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_deactive');

function add_your_fields_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'your_custom_meta_box',          // ID of the meta box
        'Location Information',          // Title of the meta box
        'your_custom_meta_box_content',  // Callback function to generate the content
        'store_post',                     // Custom post type (your_post)
        'normal',                        // Placement - 'normal', 'advanced', 'side'
        'high'                           // Priority - 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box');

function create_post_your_post() {
    register_post_type('store_post',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'         => __('Store Post'),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'thumbnail',
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array(
                'post_tag',
                'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'store_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'store_post');
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_your_post');

add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', function() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} );

function your_custom_meta_box_content($post) {
    $store_id = $post->ID;
    $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
    $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
    $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
    $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

    $default_url = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
    $image_url = '';
    if ($image_id) {
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
        if ($image_src) {
            $image_url = $image_src[0];
            $image_url = esc_url($image_url);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Image:</label></b>
    <?php
    if (!empty($image_url)) {
        echo '<br><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" style="max-width: 200px;" /><br>';
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        function previewImage(event) {
            var image = document.getElementById('image-preview');
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="your_meta_field[image]" onchange="previewImage(event)">
    <img id="image-preview" src="<?php echo !empty($image_url) ? $image_url : $default_url; ?>" height="120" width="150"/>
    <?php
    if (!empty($image_url)) {
        echo '<br><small>chosen image: ' . esc_html($image_url) . '</small>';
    } ?> <br><br>


    <b><label for="your_meta_field[image]">Address:</label></b>
    <textarea name="your_meta_field[address]" id="your_meta_field[address]" rows="3" cols="30" style="width:500px;"><?php echo esc_attr($address);?></textarea><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Latitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[latitude]" id="your_meta_field[latitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($latitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Longitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[longitude]" id="your_meta_field[longitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($longitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'your_meta_box_nonce'); ?>
    <?php
}
function save_your_custom_meta_box_data($post_id) {
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
      return;
  }
  if ('store_post' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
      return;
  }
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

  $meta_fields = isset($_POST['your_meta_field']) ? $_POST['your_meta_field'] : array();
  if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
      $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

      if (strpos($file_type, 'image') !== false) {
          $uploaded_image = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['image'], ['test_form' => false]);

          if ($uploaded_image && empty($uploaded_image['error'])) {
              $old_image_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', true);
              if ($old_image_id) {
                  wp_delete_attachment($old_image_id, true);
              }
              update_post_meta($post_id, 'image', $uploaded_image['url']);

              $attachment = array(
                  'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($uploaded_image['file']),
                  'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_image['type'],
                  'post_title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($uploaded_image['file'])),
                  'post_content'   => '',
                  'post_status'    => 'inherit'
              );

              $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $uploaded_image['file'], $post_id);
              $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $uploaded_image['file']);
              wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
              update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', $attach_id);

          } else {
              $upload_error = $uploaded_image['error'] ?? 'Image upload failed.';
              wp_die($upload_error);
          }
      } else {
          wp_die('Please upload an image file.');
      }
  }
  if (isset($meta_fields['address'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']));
  }
  if (isset($meta_fields['latitude'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'latitude', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']));
  }
  if (isset($meta_fields['longitude'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'longitude', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']));
  }
  $store_name = get_the_title($post_id);
  $description = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
  $address = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']);
  $latitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']);
  $longitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']);

  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
  $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row(
      $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE store_id = %d", $post_id)
  );

  if ($existing_record) {
      $wpdb->update(
          $table,
          array(
              'store_name' => $store_name,
              'description' => $description,
              'address' => $address,
              'latitude' => $latitude,
              'longitude' => $longitude,
          ),
          array('store_id' => $post_id),
          array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
          array('%d')
      );
  } else {
      $wpdb->insert(
          $table,
          array(
              'store_id' => $post_id,
              'store_name' => $store_name,
              'description' => $description,
              'address' => $address,
              'latitude' => $latitude,
              'longitude' => $longitude,
          ),
          array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
      );
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_your_custom_meta_box_data');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my complete code:**
*store-plugin.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Store Plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://example.com/plugins/store-plugins/
 * Description: This is a description of my store plugin.
 * Version: 2.3.1
 * Author: Khushbu
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL v2 or later
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */

function db_active()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
    store_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
    store_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    image_id INT,
    image_name VARCHAR(255),
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    latitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    longitude VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $result = dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_active');

function db_deactive()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table;";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'db_deactive');

function add_your_fields_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'your_custom_meta_box',          // ID of the meta box
        'Location Information',          // Title of the meta box
        'your_custom_meta_box_content',  // Callback function to generate the content
        'store_post',                     // Custom post type (your_post)
        'normal',                        // Placement - 'normal', 'advanced', 'side'
        'high'                           // Priority - 'high', 'core', 'default', 'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box');

function create_post_your_post()
{
    register_post_type('store_post',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'         => __('Store Post'),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'thumbnail',
            ),
            'taxonomies'   => array(
                'post_tag',
                'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'store_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'store_post');
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_your_post');

add_action('post_edit_form_tag', function () {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
});

function custom_upload_dir($upload_dir)
{
    $c_year = date('Y');
    $c_month = date('m');

    $upload_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $c_year . '/' . $c_month;
    $upload_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $c_year . '/' . $c_month;

    $upload_dir['path'] = $upload_path;
    $upload_dir['url'] = $upload_url;

    return $upload_dir;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
function your_custom_meta_box_content($post)
{
    $store_id = $post->ID;
    $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
    $image_name = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_name', true);
    $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
    $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
    $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

    $image_url = '';
    if ($image_id) {
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
        if ($image_src) {
            $image_url = $image_src[0];
            $image_url = esc_url($image_url);
        }
    }
?>
    <b><label for="your_meta_field">Image:</label></b>
    <?php
    if (!empty($image_url)) {
        echo '<br><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" id="image-preview" style="max-width: 100px;" /><br>';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="button" id="upload_button" class="button" value="Select Image">
    <input type="button" id="remove_button" class="button" value="Remove Image">
    <input type="hidden" name="your_meta_field[image_id]" id="your_meta_field[image_id]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($image_id); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="your_meta_field[image_name]" id="your_meta_field[image_name]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($image_name); ?>">
    <br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field[address]">Address:</label></b>
    <textarea name="your_meta_field[address]" id="your_meta_field[address]" rows="3" cols="30" style="width:500px;"><?php echo esc_attr($address); ?></textarea><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field[latitude]">Latitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[latitude]" id="your_meta_field[latitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($latitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <b><label for="your_meta_field[longitude]">Longitude:</label></b>
    <input type="text" name="your_meta_field[longitude]" id="your_meta_field[longitude]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($longitude); ?>"><br><br>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var filee;
            function openMediaUploader() {
                if (filee) {
                    filee.open();
                    return;
                }
                filee = wp.media.frames.filee = wp.media({
                    title: 'Select Image',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Choose Image',
                    },
                    multiple: false,
                });
                filee.on('select', function () {
                    var attachment = filee.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    console.log(attachment);

                    $('#your_meta_field\\[image_id\\]').val(attachment.id);
                    $('#your_meta_field\\[image_name\\]').val(attachment.filename); 
                    $('#image-preview').attr('src', attachment.url);
                });

                filee.open();
            }
            $(document).on('click', '#upload_button', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                openMediaUploader();
            });
            var imageId = $('#your_meta_field\\[image_id\\]').val();
            var imageFilename = $('#your_meta_field\\[image_name\\]').val();
            if (imageId && imageFilename) {
                var imageSrc = wp.media.attachment(imageId).get('url');
                $('#image-preview').attr('src', imageSrc);
            }
            $(document).on('click', '#remove_button', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#your_meta_field\\[image_id\\]').val(''); // Clear the image ID field
                $('#your_meta_field\\[image_name\\]').val(''); // Clear the image name field
                $('#image-preview').attr('src', ''); 
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'your_meta_box_nonce'); ?>
<?php
}

function save_your_custom_meta_box_data($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return;
    }
    if ('store_post' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
        return;
    }

    $meta_fields = isset($_POST['your_meta_field']) ? $_POST['your_meta_field'] : array();
    $image_name = isset($meta_fields['image_name']) ? sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['image_name']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_name', $image_name);

    if (!empty($_FILES['your_meta_field']['name']['image_name'])) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['your_meta_field']['name']['image_name'], array('test_form' => false));

        if ($uploaded_file && !isset($uploaded_file['error'])) {
            $image_name = sanitize_file_name(basename($uploaded_file['file']));
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_name', $image_name);

            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment(array(
                'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($uploaded_file['file'])),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            ), $uploaded_file['file'], $post_id);

            if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $uploaded_file['file']);
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
            }
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
            if ($image_url) {
                $image_name = $image_url;
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_name', $image_name);
            }
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', $attachment_id);            
        }
    } else {      
        $image_id = absint($meta_fields['image_id']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_id', $image_id);
        $existing_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
        if ($existing_image_url) {
            $image_name = $existing_image_url;
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'image_name', $image_name);
        }
    }

    if (isset($meta_fields['address'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']));
    }
    if (isset($meta_fields['latitude'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'latitude', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']));
    }
    if (isset($meta_fields['longitude'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'longitude', sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']));
    }

    $store_name = get_the_title($post_id);
    $description = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $address = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['address']);
    $latitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['latitude']);
    $longitude = sanitize_text_field($meta_fields['longitude']);

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'store_db';
    $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE store_id = %d", $post_id)
    );
    if ($existing_record) {
        $wpdb->update(
            $table,
            array(
                'store_name' => $store_name,
                'image_name' => $image_name, 
                'description' => $description,
                'address' => $address,
                'latitude' => $latitude,
                'longitude' => $longitude,
            ),
            array('store_id' => $post_id),
            array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
            array('%d')
        );
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table,
            array(
                'store_id' => $post_id,
                'store_name' => $store_name,
                'image_name' => $image_name,
                'description' => $description,
                'address' => $address,
                'latitude' => $latitude,
                'longitude' => $longitude,
            ),
            array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
        );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_your_custom_meta_box_data');
?>
```

*single-store.php*

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
  the_content();
  $store_id = get_the_ID();
  $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
  $image_name = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_name', true);
  $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
  $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
  $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

  if ($image_id) {
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
    if ($image_src) {
        $image_url = $image_src[0];
    }
}
?>

<div class="store-location-info">
    <?php if (!empty($image_url)) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="max-width: 200px;">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($image_name)) : ?>
    <p><strong>Image Name:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($image_name); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p><strong>Address:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($address); ?></p>
    <p><strong>Latitude:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($latitude); ?></p>
    <p><strong>Longitude:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($longitude); ?></p>
</div>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

*template-location-records.php*

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main">
    <?php  
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'store_post', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
    ?>
      <table class="store-locations-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Store Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Latitude</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
          while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            $store_name = get_the_title();
            $description = get_the_content();
            $image_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'image_id', true);
            $address = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'address', true);
            $latitude = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true);
            $longitude = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true);

            $image_url = '';
            if ($image_id) {
                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
                if ($image_src) {
                    $image_url = $image_src[0];
                }
            }
            ?>
              <tr>
              <td><?php echo esc_html($store_name); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo esc_html($description); ?></td>
              <td>
                  <?php if (!empty($image_url)) : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($store_name); ?>" style="max-width: 100px;">
                  <?php else : ?>
                      <p>No image available</p>
                  <?php endif; ?>
              </td>    
              <td><?php echo esc_html($address); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo esc_html($latitude); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo esc_html($longitude); ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php
          endwhile;
          ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <?php
    else :
      echo '<p>No location records found.</p>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </main>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

- This file is located in your current activated theme for me
  :C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressphp\wp-content\themes\zakra this file is
  located here i placed my code here.

*functions.php*

//my-location function

```
function display_location_info_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $store_id = get_the_ID();
            $image_id = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_id', true);
            $image_name = get_post_meta($store_id, 'image_name', true);
            $address = get_post_meta($store_id, 'address', true);
            $latitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'latitude', true);
            $longitude = get_post_meta($store_id, 'longitude', true);

            $image_url = '';
            if ($image_id) {
                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
                if ($image_src) {
                    $image_url = $image_src[0];
                }
            }
            ?>
            <div class="store-location-info">
                <?php if (!empty($image_url)) : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="max-width: 200px;">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (!empty($image_name)) : ?>
                    <p><strong>Image Path:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($image_name); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p><strong>Address:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($address); ?></p>
                <p><strong>Latitude:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($latitude); ?></p>
                <p><strong>Longitude:</strong> <?php echo esc_html($longitude); ?></p>
            </div>

        <?php
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo '<p>No location records found.</p>';
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('display_location_info', 'display_location_info_shortcode');
```

Thank you :)